# how to apply border radius to canvas element like div to make it circle?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

i want to make canvas element circle like other any div but its not working. here is my code . please have a loot at code. what am doing wrong with border-radius propoerty ?

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="background-color:red;border:1px solid;border-radius:50%">
```

border-radius property is not working like i apply on div. actually, i want to create rectangle , square and circle of canvas. please anyone can help me

`

Comment: your code works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Border radius should do it however if you are using JavaScript this method might help:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: @what are these values  100, 75, 59, 0 in ctx.arc ?

Comment: context.arc(x,y,r,sAngle,eAngle,counterclockwise);

x/y: The x,y-coordinate of the center of the circle
r: The radius of the circle
sAngle: Starting angle of the circle in radians (0 is at 3:00 position on the clock)
eAngle: Ending angle of the circle in radians
counterclockwise: sets if drawing should be set to counterclockwise. False is default.

Comment: As an addition to my comment: the sAngle is also normally *Math.PI but I left it out in this case because 0 * Math.PI = 0. Math.PI just outputs 3.14159... which is needed to make a circle.